# klish server start failing with latest 3.0.0

Tags: c, xml, clish

Posting here as I didn't hear back anything on the mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/g/klish/c/wQsFFAU1lzc).

On `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`, built the latest version `3.0.0` of `klish`

```bash
git clone https://src.libcode.org/pkun/faux.git
cd faux
./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && sudo make install

cd ..
git clone https://src.libcode.org/pkun/klish.git
cd klish
./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Trying to start the server ...

```bash
/usr/local/bin/klishd -d -v -f ./klishd.conf
klishd: Parse config file: ../klishd.conf
klishd: opts: Foreground = true
klishd: opts: Verbose = true
klishd: opts: LogFacility = daemon
klishd: opts: PIDPath = /var/run/klishd.pid
klishd: opts: ConfigPath = ../klishd.conf
klishd: opts: UnixSocketPath = /tmp/klish-unix-socket
klishd: opts: DBs = libxml2
klishd: Start daemon.
Scheme errors:
DB "libxml2": kdb-libxml2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
DB "libxml2": Can't load DB plugin
klishd: Stop daemon.
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Eventually I am trying to connect the client `klish` to the server `klishd`.

Comment: better post this on github itself

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen The klish project is not hosted on github, but on a different git server. They do have a link to a Google Group of the project. As mentioned at the top of the question, I have already posted there but didn't hear back, hence trying here.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem during installation. libxml2 is not enabled by default.

```
./configure --with-libxml2=/usr
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).